# Create multi-dimensional PHP array with named keys

Tags: php, arrays

I know i can create an array like this:

```
$array = (
    array(
        array(
            array('MyGroup', 'Name', '0'),
            array('MyGroup', 'Name', "1"),
            array('MyGroup', 'Name', "2"),
        )
    )

);

print_r($array);
echo "<br>";

echo $array[0][0][0]. "<br>";
echo $array[0][0][1]. "<br>";
echo $array[0][0][2]. "<br>";
```

What if i'd like to name the keys/index with names like:
`echo $array['MyGroup']['Name']['Id];`

I tried to create them "on the fly":
`$array['MyGroup']['Name']['id'] = "0";`

How can i do this?

**UPDATE**

But i cannot figure out how to add key & value "class":

```
$array['01']['Name'] = "David";
print_r($array);
echo "<br>";

echo $array['01']['Name'];
echo "<br>";

$array['02']['Name'] = "Eva";
print_r($array);
echo "<br>";

echo $array['02']['Name'];
echo "<br>";

$array['02']['Name']['class'] = "five";
print_r($array);
echo "<br>";

Array ( [01] => Array ( [Name] => David ) ) 
David
Array ( [01] => Array ( [Name] => David ) [02] => Array ( [Name] => Eva  ) ) 
Eva
Array ( [01] => Array ( [Name] => David ) [02] => Array ( [Name] => Eva  [David] => Array ( [class] => five ) ) )
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$students = array( 
    "0" => array (
        "Name" => "Eve",
        "Class" => "Five"
    ),

    "1" => array (
        "Name" => "David",
        "Class" => "Nine"
    ),

    "2" => array (
        "Name" => "Eve",
        "Class" => "Four"
    )
);

print_r($students);
```

How can i create a array like this, "On the fly"?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Yes you can, but be sure that `Id != id`

Comment: @Rizier123 Check Updated question.

Comment: I don't see what the problem now is?

Comment: @Rizier123 If you check the last row. $array['02] Name is Eva.. Then it says David => array.. where it should be Class => five

Comment: @BjörnC I can't reproduce your output, so you definitely don't show us your real output or code here. But I can tell you that you set a value here: `$array['02']['Name'] = "Eva";` and then you try to overwrite it here: `$array['02']['Name']['class'] = "five";` which won't work as you want.

Comment: @Rizier123 So can you please help me how can i give array [01] more keys than Name.. i'd like it to be: `Array ( [01] => Array ( [Name] => David ) Array( [Class] => Five))`

Comment: @Rizier123 Check Update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on the fly but be careful to avoid overwritting the value of your array.

If you do this you are going to overwrite always the $array['MyGroup']['Name']['id'] value since you are always in the same position.

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $array['MyGroup']['Name']['id'] = $value;
}
```

You should do this instead changing the literal 'id' for the $key value or the id value of the item:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $array['MyGroup']['Name'][$key] = $value;
}
```

**Edit to update 2:**

You should give us how is your data source to create the array on the fly but this is an example to achieve the structure you want assuming the data structure incoming like that:

```
$data->Object->Name
$data->Object->Class
```

And one solution could be this:

```
$students = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $students[][$key] = $value;
}
```

If you want to do it by hand just use:

```
$students[] = array('Name' => $name, 'Class' => $class);
```

Anyway if we can not see where the data is coming we can not help you correctly.

Comment: Please check my "Update 2", this is what i want!

Comment: I updated the answer. If you still stuck please provide more information about the data source type. Regards!

Comment: Awesome, thank you!